# Python USB-CAN communication

Tags: python, can-bus

I have a stepper MKS SERVO42D and an USB-CAN adapter. I am trying to create a python code where I can implement some functions to control the servo but I get errors at USB-CAN communications. I am a begginer in automatizations and I don't know how to resolve my problem. My code look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import can
can_interface = 0 
bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='usb2can', channel=can_interface)
def go_back_to_zero():
    command = [0x01, 0x3B]
    message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x123, data=command)
    bus.send(message)
def rotate_left():
    command = [0x01, 0xF6, 0x01, 0x40, 0x02, 0x3A]
    message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x123, data=command)
    bus.send(message)
def rotate_right():
    command = [0x01, 0xF6, 0x81, 0x40, 0x02, 0xBA]
    message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x123, data=command)
    bus.send(message)
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Control Servomotor")
window.geometry("500x500")
btn_left = tk.Button(window, text="Rotește la stânga", command=rotate_left)
btn_left.pack(pady=10)
btn_right = tk.Button(window, text="Rotește la dreapta", command=rotate_right)
btn_right.pack(pady=10)
btn_go_back_to_zero = tk.Button(window, text="Go Back to Zero", command=go_back_to_zero)
btn_go_back_to_zero.pack(pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

When I tried to run the code it says that usb2can can not be find. I tried to search some libraries from  GitHub for usb2can but is not working. Can you tell me what I need to do or you have any document to use for this type of communications? Much thanks

Comment: Did you have a wee look here?
https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/interfaces.html

Are you on Windows or Linux? Install instructions here:
https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/interfaces/usb2can.html